# Where condition in SOQL using Formula Field is not running

Tags: apex, soql, formula-field

I made a query. there is field formula named Source__c, but when i set value source != 'PT1', the code will give value contact that in source PT1 too.

This is my source__c formula

```
IF( CONTAINS( Owner.Profile.Name, "SPS") , "SPS", IF(CONTAINS(Owner.Profile.Name, "FSL"), "FSL", Owner.Profile.Name) )
```

and this is my query

```
SELECT MobilePhone, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE MobilePhone IN :contactMobilePhones AND AccountId IN :AccountIDs AND Id Not IN :contactIDs AND Source__c != 'PT1' GROUP BY MobilePhone,AccountId
```

and this is the result
[image]

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: weird, try `(NOT (Source__c LIKE '%PT1%'))`

Comment: Good Catch @Damecek . I figured out this is because of prefixed space .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Value of `Profile.Name` used in custom formula fields will show the internal database name PTN where “N” is a number.

For example System Administrator  is considered as  `PT1`(Note this has prefix  as space )

I have also come across this [know issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000181gKQAQ) according to in the example the profile.name should be treated as  `PT1`.

So your SOQL query should be modified as below.

```
SELECT MobilePhone, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE MobilePhone IN :contactMobilePhones AND AccountId IN :AccountIDs AND Id Not IN :contactIDs AND Source__c != ' PT1' GROUP BY MobilePhone,AccountId
```